# cron not running specific command

Tags: cron

I have a simple script and asking crontab to execute that script. In the script, I have 2 commands I want to run and append the output to a file. Only one of the commands does as it should. However, if I run the script myself as 'root', the script works. All the machines, RHEL, Ubuntu Server/Desktop and Fedora have the same outcome. Below is my script and `crontab -l`.

I have been researching and trying everything, even setting the `$PATH`, but nothing. The `service httpd status` will not run.

```
#!/bin/bash

#check httpd status and append to file
service httpd status >> /path/to/file;

#check cupsd status and append to file
netstat -punta | grep cupsd >> /path/to/file;

exit
```

Crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash

#check httpd status and output to file
service httpd status >> /var/log/messages;

#check pptpd status and append to file
netstat -punta | grep cupsd >> /var/log/messages;

exit

Comment: personal crontab? You might (probably don't) have permission to write to /var/log/messages.

Comment: the netstat command will write. if i run the script, it runs correctly

Comment: output from 'root' running script                                        [root@localhost ~]# /usr/local/bin/services_1.sh 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  httpd.service
[root@localhost ~]# cat /var/log/messages 
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
tcp   0  0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1975/cupsd          
tcp6   0         0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1975/cupsd

Comment: output from crontab running - [root@localhost ~]# cat /var/log/messages 
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1975/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1975/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1975/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1975/cup

Comment: -bash /usr/local/bin/services.sh----------rw-r--r-- 1 root root 255 Aug 29  2012 /etc/crontab-----------rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 350 Jun  9 00:05 script.sh------------Shell, cron permissions, script permissions respectively

Comment: `/var/log/messages` is a syslog file; you should not be overwriting this with anything.

Comment: I am not overwriting, instead appending (>>) to the file. This file is what gives me other messages through email and I would like to know some more info about my system. I understand and appreciate the concern, however, the platform this is intended for is RHEL. The output you see above was only created on my VM for testing and never had that file to begin with.

Comment: I actually looked at that forum as well. I did 4 days of research on this, prior to posting the question. Only when I was able to view cronlog on my VPS, I was able to see the error message. Thanks Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Instead of running 'service httpd status' run '/etc/init.d/httpd status

This has worked flawlessly. What keyed me onto this was attempting to run this in Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, I looked at the cron log for errors, found the errors online and substituted the above.